# PHP mysqldump file import

Tags: php, mysql

I want backup my local database and import that database from live website. I'm tried something. please see below..

My Backup code

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root";  
$dbpass = 'password'; 
$dbname = "database"; 

$backupfile ='database.sql';
$backupdir = dirname(__FILE__);
$source = $backupdir.'/'.$backupfile;
system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser --password='$dbpass' $dbname  > $backupfile");

?>
<form action="http://www.example.com/restore_database.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="backup_file" value="<?php echo $source; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

my restore_database.php (example.com/restore_database.php)

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = "database";
$filename = $_POST['backup_file'];

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

$templine = '';
$lines = file($filename);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
        continue;
    $templine .= $line;
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
        mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
        $templine = '';
    }
}
?>
```

In my localhost , I'm successfully tested this. for my live site I think file path not detect correctly. I have no idea about this. please help me. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use a shell script instead of leaving these URLS (*example.com/restore_database.php*) open to the users to play with

... on your server add the simple scripts to backup/restore or add a script on your local host to connect to the remote server and backup/restore.

Comment: Sorry , I'm new to php. can you show an example...

Comment: ok can you tell me if you want to have the backup on the local or live server ?

Comment: i have an localhost appliaction. i want backup that database and restore to my live site database.

Comment: so you have access to the live site ... and you want to backup the data on a directory on the live site or on a directory on your localhost ?

Comment: i want update my live website database from localhost database. i have access to the live site.

Comment: please comment on the answer so i'll be able to refine it with exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

assuming that the live site lay on the ip **134.122.12.109**
and you are using UNIX

on your local host create these files and `~/backupdir` directory

### backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uusername -pPassword database > ~/backupdir/backupFile.sql
```

---

### restore.sh

```
#!/bin.bash
mysql -h 134.122.12.109 -uliveSiteUsername -pLiveSitePassword database < ~/backupdir/backupFile.sql
```

now you can backup your localhost by running `./backup.sh`

and you can restore the live site by using `./restore.sh`

hope that demonstrated the idea.

---

**responding to your comment**

let the restore_database.php be

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = "database";
$filename = $_POST['backup_file'];
system("mysql -h $dbhost -u $dbuser --password='$dbpass' $dbname < $filename");
?>
```

Comment: 1) my website hosted in shared ip. 2) my application run on wamp 3)in my question method , i just want one click. all other process will do jquery.

Comment: in that case i suggest you go with the scripts method... and since you run windows the you will have to know where mysql directory is. and where mysqldump directory is. they are probably in 'C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysqldump.exe' and in 'C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysql.exe'. so you have to run `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysqldump.exe -uusername -pPassword database > file.sql` to backup and run `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysql.exe -h 134.122.12.109 -uliveSiteUsername -pLiveSitePassword database < file.sql` to restore from the cmd yourself